# como puedo mandar un audio por un api rest c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-forms, audio, webapi

Buenas tengo un problema intento mandar un a un api para consumirlo

Para hacerlo hago lo siguiente

- Escojo el archivo con un windows forms
- Lo convierto a `bite[]`

Y lo mando al api y hasta ahí bien. Pero el api en el momento de llamarlo lo recibe como `null`, la cuestión es que cuando mando un archivo normal de texto o fotos,  cualquier tipo de archivo que no es audio, si me lo recibe.

Creo que es por que el archivo es muy grande. También lo intente con base64 pero nada. ¿Alguien sabe como mandar un audio y que un api asp lo tome? Gracias.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { try { if( this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) { byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(openFileDialog1.FileName); ByteArrayContent byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(b);

                var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(b, 0, b.Length);
                var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:63601/api/AudioEntrada/GenerarAudioPOST");
                httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
                using (var stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    Audio objTemp = new Audio()
                    {
                        AudioBit = b,
                        AudioFormato = base64
                    };
                    var bodyTemp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objTemp));
                    stream.Write(bodyTemp, 0, bodyTemp.Length);
                }
           HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
           StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
           string mensaje = sr.ReadToEnd();
           httpWebRequest.GetResponse().Close();
           }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        throw;
        }
    }



      [HttpPost]
       public string GenerarAudioPOST(Audio c)
       {

        }

/// y este es el objeto

public class Audio
   {
       public byte[] AudioBit { get; set; }
       public string AudioFormato { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: si quieres estar seguro que se debe al tamanio del archivo intenta con uno pequeno, genera un archivo con un hola